SwiftUI View transition not working when new element appears
If the view isn't directly controlled by enter, it will ignore the transition.
Adding drawingGroup can change this behavior, but it's still not ideal.
Imagine the .onAppear closure is the data from the network, or is there any other way to arrange the view?
struct TestView: View {
    @State var enter = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("view enter"){
                withAnimation{
                    enter.toggle()
                }
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 30)
            if enter{
                ChildView()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
            
        }//.drawingGroup() 
    }
}
struct ChildView: View {
    @State var newElement = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 30)
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
            ForEach(0..<newElement,id:\.self){i in
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 30)
            }// the newly appeared view will ignore the transition, how to solve that.
        }
        .onAppear{
                newElement = 2
        }
    }
}


Why did you expect the rectangles in the ForEach to use the same transaction as the whole ChildView? newElement = 2 isn't even wrapped with withAnimation. It makes more sense to put drawingGroup (or geometryGroup if that's available) on the ChildView instead of the whole outer VStack.

If you want the newly-added rows to "join in" the transition that the ChildView is already undergoing, try applying  .geometryGroup() to the VStack in ChildView (requires iOS 17):
// ChildView

VStack {
    // ...
}
.geometryGroup() //  added
.onAppear {
    newElement = 2
}

To see exactly what is happening, it helps to add a Spacer to the VStack in TestView, so that the parent content doesn't move when the child content is added. You might also like to activate "Slow Animations" on the simulator, or add a longer duration to the animation:
// TestView

VStack {
    Button("view enter") {
        withAnimation(.spring(duration: 2)) { //  animation made longer
            enter.toggle()
        }
    }
    Rectangle()
        .frame(height: 30)
    if enter {
        ChildView()
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    }
    Spacer() //  added
}



If you are not able to use geometryGroup then another way to solve it is to add separate transitions to the rows being added and perform the change withAnimation:
// ChildView

VStack {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(height: 30)
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
    ForEach(0..<newElement,id:\.self) { i in
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 30)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom)) //  added
    }
}
.onAppear {
    withAnimation(.spring(duration: 2)) { //  added
        newElement = 2
    }
}


